# Is this order of the quantified variables correct for the definition of Big O?

Tags: optimization, asymptotics, definition

So Big O says that for a function $f(x)$ to be in $O(g(x))$, then for some $C$, $k$, and all $x$, if $x > k$ then $f(x) \le Cg(x)$.

My question is whether this order of the quantified variables is correct, or does it not matter? While $\exists x\forall y(R(x,y))$ implies $\forall y\exists x(R(x,y))$, the same is not true for the converse. So generally speaking it's not safe to disregard the order (although for the case of Big O maybe it is?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order does matter, and that it is incorrect to write the $x$ with the universal quantifier first. If this was done, then it would be easy to show any $f(x)$ is $O(g(x))$. For each $x$, just pick a $k$ greater than $x$. This causes $x > k$ to be false, making the conditional vacuously true. Another solution is to just make $C$ arbitrarily big, such that $C(g(x))$ will surpass the value of $f(x)$ for the current $x$ being examined.

By having the existential variables first, a particular value for each of them must be picked before getting to the $x$ variable.